# SQL Server 2008 works, same settings and instance on SQLSRV 2012 doesnt

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I hope anyone can help me out on this one .. I've been trying to figure out for hours what's happening.

Our office requires us to use SQL Server 2012, and there's a desktop app that has been working fine with 2008 (A custom made VB program). When migrating the same database, using a same name instance of SQL Server 2012, the program will stop connecting (throws this message: 
**[DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Connect()).]  Sql server does not exist or access denied**

I just cant figure out why. I uninstall SQL Server 2012 and put back SQL Server 2008 with the same instance, and the program just works but I need it to work with 2012 .. Has anyone faced something similar?

Comment: Do you know what user the app connects as?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid yes, as "sa"

Comment: OK so when you installed SQL 2012, you enable both Windows _and_ SQL Server authentication? And you then went and changed the sa password to match whatever your app is using? Just a side note: if your app is using sa / sa or sa / blank or sa / password, you need to decomission it now before the next SQL Server virus hits.

Comment: Yes, enabled both authentication modes and set the "sa" password the same as the previous instance of SQL Server 2008. Unfortunately the person who made the program passed away and no source code was released. On the good side, we use this on a domain-only network, with no internet access.

Comment: My commiserations. The next thing to try is install SSMS (2012) and try and connect as _sa_ from there. You might get a better error message. Also you can more easily check the error logs which might also have more information. You can also try the UDL connection test. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/farukcelik/2007/12/31/basics-first-udl-test/ Which makes me think: perhaps the app is using a connection string which uses a provider which doesn't work against SQL 2012.

Comment: Is this anything to do with you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44512690/sql-server-2008-works-same-settings-and-instance-on-sqlsrv-2012-doesnt?noredirect=1#comment76020070_44512690

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid no, I now tried with the same SQL SRV 2008 instance, but with the 2012 databases (imported via Azure Migration Wizard) and its the same thing. It seems something happens with those db once they touch 2012 ....

Comment: AFAIK Azure migration wizard is for migrating databases to Azure. Is your SQL server a local one or Azure? Don't use a wizard. Just restore the 2008 backup into SQL 2012.

Comment: You need to methodically test: 1. Install SQL 2012. Can you connect with sa? 2. Restore DB backups. Can you connect with sa?